# Echoing HTML links

Tags: php, mysql, navigation, hyperlink, echo

If I am calling a list of links from a mysql table named categories I think I use a select statement like:

```
  $query = "SELECT cat_name, cat_description FROM categories";
  $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
    or die('Error querying database.');

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '$row';
  }
```

These categories have been joined with a business_info table in a mapping_table (they have a many to many relationship). I think that at the moment this will echo a string for each category name so I don't understand how I make my echoed results active links which will display the business info when clicked.

I know that once clicked they will issue a SELECT statement to the mapping_table which i'm cool with. the bit i'm struggling with is making them clickable to issue that statement. Any ideas, i'm lost!

EDIT: I edited out the AND clause. I was wrong.

Comment: Are you having trouble adding the html around your URL?

Comment: `"SELECT cat_name AND cat_description FROM categories"` is not valid MySQL.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal, there is no syntax error, so it IS valid in MySQL.

Comment: @Jrod your spot on. Though Marc B has answered the question I was so terrible at asking :0) a simple thing that wasn't making sense to me. I feel a little daft now having seen the answer. Thanks all!

Comment: @binaryLV: Well, ok, it *is* valid MySQL, but it's certainly not what the OP intended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your SQL is invalid. It shoudd be

```
SELECT cat_name, cat_description FROM categories
```

Your die() clause should be

```
... or die (mysql_error())
```

so you can see exactly what the error was (a fixed string is useless for debugging purposes). And then your retrieval loop should be:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo <<<EOL
<a href="script.php?category={$row['cat_name']}">{$row['cat_description']}</a>

EOL;
}
```

Comment: There's no syntax error in his query, i.e., his SQL query is not invalid. Though, it probably is not what he wanted to select. And `die()` should **never** output result of `mysql_error()`, as it is sensitive information. Result of `mysql_error()` may be logged somewhere (either manually, or by using `trigger_error(mysql_error())` and letting PHP handle logging it), but it should never be shown to end user.

Comment: A query which doesn't produce the results you want is a syntax error. "field  AND otherfield" is not what the OP wants. And for debugging purposes, die() is valid. I agree it should not be used on a production system, but while testing, it's invaluable.

Comment: "syntax error" is something that cannot be parsed by the parser. Even if the query would contain invalid table or field names, it would NOT be a *syntax* error. In this case, it is rather *logical* error or something like that. About using `die()` for debugging purposes - well, how often do people replace all those `die()` with some neat error handling functionality? If it is for debugging purpose, add `die(mysql_error())` only when real error occurs rather than put it there and forget about it.